# Pathfinding with cycles in a graph (Use each edge once)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path-finding

I would like to search for some paths in a graph. Graph has cycles, they happen quite often.

Bring back the old riddle about drawing house without putting up pen and drawing same edge 2 times.

```
  ^
 / \
/ _ \
|\ /|
| x |
|/_\|
```

It has 5 vertices and 8 edges. Let us say that I want to check if it's possible to draw such a graph without "putting up the pen", with given starting vertex. Notice, that i can (and probably need) to process same vertex with different map state (are the edges around used?) few times. Do I have to make a copy of the whole edge-usage array for each node while running BFS/DFS? Is there any simple method to do that?

Comment: A random fact - The path will always start and end at the vertices with an odd number of edges, if any such vertices exist.

Comment: I want to know the path tho.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with bfs/dfs.

Comment: DFS or BFS would visit each node ONCE. You need to visit all EDGES, not nodes. This will require visiting single vertex more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DFS, you just need to have visited flag on the edge. You don't need to copy it, just reset it after the call.

Pseudo-code:

```
for each node
  for each edge
    edge.visited = false
  dfs(node)

dfs(node)
  // do something with node?
  // perhaps check numberOfEdges == visited.size() to see if we're done
  for each edge in node
    if (!edge.visited)
      edge.visited = true
      dfs(edge.other(node))
      edge.visited = false
```

Comment: Oh... Seems pretty legit. Any way to improve BFS that way?

Comment: @kittyPL With BFS each path will have to keep track of it's own set of visited flags, which you have to check against when checking the neighbours, and copy it for each of them.

Comment: Since DFS is satisfying, I wouldn't bother to do it iterative way :) Thank you, accepting answer right now :)

Answer (score 0):

> Let us say that I want to check if it's possible to draw such a graph without "putting up the pen", with given starting vertex.

If graph isn't connected, drawing is impossible. Otherwise, if graph doesn't have vertices of odd [degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_degree), it is possible, no matter what vertex you start from. If it has two such vertices, it is possible if and only if given vertex has odd degree. If it has more than two vertices of odd degree, it is impossible.

> I would like to search for some paths in a graph.

If drawing is possible (see above), **any** path will do as long as remaining edges are connected.

Comment: I want to know ALL paths that satisfy my needs. You just gave true/false solution that I knew of before.

Comment: @kittyPL Well, sorry for that, though it wasn't obvious from your question.

Comment: No problem. Actually, "Let us say" is a very important part. I need this for quite different task, although I used the riddle as example (the algorithm would be exactly the same).